# How do I calculate the average of 2 exchange rates?

Tags: linear-algebra

An exchange rate of 2, when reversed is 0.5. Calculated using 1/x.
I believe this is correct because: v / 2 = v * 0.5

The next day the exchange rate is 2.5, when reversed is 0.4. Calculated using 1/y.

The average exchange rate (AER) over the two days is 2.25. Calculated using (x + y) / 2.

I believe this is correct because:

(((v * x) + (v * y)) / 2) / AER = v

However I cannot reverse this in the same way because this equation doesn't balance:

(((v * (1/x)) + (v * (1/y)) / 2) / (1/AER) != v

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please format using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Why to "reverse" ? if you have $a$ and $b$ you have $\text {AV}= \dfrac {a+b}{2}$.

Comment: If you "reverse" you will have $\text {AV'}= \dfrac { (\frac 1 a + \frac 1 b)}{2}= \dfrac {a +b }{2ab}$.

Comment: Thanks Mauro. What is the relationship between AV' and AV? Is there anyway to get AV' from AV without using a and b? This is ultimately what I am trying to do. I don't understand why the relationship between AV' and AV is different to a' and b.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an oddity of the arithmetic mean (the typical one of adding and dividing by $2$).  The average of the reciprocals is not usually the reciprocal of the average.  In some cases, maybe this one, the geometric mean may be more appropriate.  The is the square root of the product.

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly the explanation I needed.